# How to include diary data/lagged data in multilevel regression code

Tags: longitudinal, multilevel-analysis

I work with diary data and I am trying to do a multilevel regression with a lagged variable. I try to

1. predict a binary variable from a continuous variable of the previous day and
2. To predict a continuous variable from a binary variable of the previous day.

I don't understand how to include this time lag/diary data format into the R code. Also, I do not know how to control for the predictor variable from the same day.

I use the lmer and glmer command for continuous and binary outcomes and so far only level 1 predictors

```
lmer<-(pred.binary.previousday~outcome.cont.+1(1|level2),data=data)

lmer<-(pred.binary.previousday~outcome.cont.+1(pred.binary.previousday|level2),data=data)

glmer<-(pred.cont.previousday~outcome.binary.+1(1|level2),family(link=binomial),data=data)
```

AIC did not show a better fit of random coefficients, but that I was expecting. regression results so far were not significant, but maybe that is because I did not write the code correctly.